# Conjunctive Normal Form representation/ First Order Logic.

Tags: logic

in my research problem, I need to represent three types of three types of relationships between the variables x,y as the following::

1. " y Cooperates with x" relationship: means if there is two variables x,y. then the increasing of satisfaction of x will lead to increase the satisfaction of y.

** I did linear representation such: y= ax+b

1. " y Contradicts with x" relationship: means if there is two variables x,y. then the increasing of satisfaction of x will lead to decrease the satisfaction of y.

** I did linear representation such: y= -ax+b

1. "y Irrelevant with x" relationship: means if there is two variables x,y. then the increasing/decreasing of satisfaction of x will NOT affect to increasing/decreasing the satisfaction of y.

** I did this linear representation such: y=b, where b is constant value and y is constant function.

So, please How can I represented those relationships by using FIRST ORDER LOGIC or conjunctive normal form?

Comment: Did you post this question earlier? - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863729/first-order-logic

Comment: Yes I asked it before